# iOS: MMDrawController: How to disable pangesture on specific view of viewcontroller

Tags: ios, mmdrawercontroller, residemenu

I have configured `MMDrawController` in my application which has `UITabBarController` as `initialviewcontroller`.

```
 self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.rootTabBarController leftDrawerViewController:leftSideNavigationController];
   self.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
    self.drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;

    [self.drawerController setGestureShouldRecognizeTouchBlock:^BOOL(MMDrawerController *drawerController, UIGestureRecognizer *gesture, UITouch *touch) {

        if ([gesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        return !([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) && !([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) && !([touch.view isKindOfClass:[ADNetworkFeedDropdownView class]]) && [gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]];

    }];
```

However one of the viewcontroller has infinite scrollview, when I swipe on infinite scrollview of that specific viewcontroller I want to disable pan of `MMDrawViewController`. Currently, Left pan opens up if I swipe on the scrollview. I tried `becomeFirstresponder`, Its not working.

Comment: use `self.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModeNone`

Comment: I want gesture to be there but not on that specific view of the viewcontroller.